# KSQLDB - failing docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ksqldb

I am trying to setup KSQLDB setup in my ubuntu 18.04. I am following the steps:
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/installing/

I am doing step by step how it saying.

But when I run `docker-compose up` I get this error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 80, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 189, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[7677] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: This looks like a Compose error connecting to the Docker Daemon, not related to KsqlDB

Comment: can you do a docker ps ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to not having your linux user added to the docker group.

By default, you need to run Docker-related commands with sudo permissions.

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

---

To add your user to the group, do this:

Create the group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Add your current user to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Reload group permissions

```
newgrp docker
```